# How can I use styled-components to change an element in svg with a specific id?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to give a mouse over effect by region on the map.

[image]

I'm using `React` and `styled-components`. I want to assign an id to the svg `<path>` and change only the fill value of the path when the mouse is over.

```
<path id="areaA-name" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M546.173 508.974C549.935 503.186 553.954 497.461 556.675 491.184C557.635 488.979 555.563 485.093 554.212 482.311C551.402 476.514 548.138 470.939 544.368 463.995C542.803 464.938 539.958 466.769 536.988 468.37C535.609 469.108 533.955 469.872 532.47 469.775C515.673 468.752 508.541 473.9 505.011 490.526C503.073 499.665 502.219 509.045 500.049 518.123C499.169 521.822 496.723 527.147 493.896 527.974C487.725 529.77 480.46 529.245 475.889 523.582C470.5 516.887 466.01 509.481 460.63 501.657C454.005 503.924 447.541 501.017 441.138 496.892C436.55 493.931 431.597 493.006 426.146 495.842C421.104 498.474 416.062 496.358 412.149 490.57C409.117 486.08 406.521 481.67 411.945 476.647C419.37 469.757 426.19 462.2 433.562 455.238C440.8 448.41 440.507 440.781 432.015 435.803C426.252 432.424 420.197 429.49 414.115 426.716C410.06 424.867 408.032 422.938 409.695 417.95C411.954 411.202 411.189 404.587 409.873 397.279C408.432 389.321 406.369 382.235 402.626 375.283C402.092 374.287 402.688 371.789 403.595 371.131C404.858 370.224 407.134 369.717 408.584 370.206C418.827 373.638 426.457 368.321 425.728 357.101C425.39 351.864 427.453 348.628 430.53 345.321C437.812 337.506 447.167 333.754 457.438 332.207C462.648 331.424 468.224 330.322 473.204 331.389C484.328 333.771 489.699 328.517 495.567 319.911C501.854 310.691 508.684 300.671 521.444 298.439C522.386 298.27 523.587 295.363 523.365 293.932C523.125 292.349 521.266 291.069 520.323 289.522C519.15 287.601 518.198 285.556 517.158 283.565C519.781 283.076 522.644 281.689 524.965 282.311C527.891 283.094 530.976 285.005 532.942 287.326C539.975 295.639 548.539 298.244 558.622 294.67C565.309 292.296 571.649 288.962 578.176 286.143C584.748 283.307 591.106 281.475 597.508 287.157C599.767 289.166 603.448 289.548 606.436 290.766C610.864 292.58 613.203 291.238 614.377 286.508C615.133 283.476 616.306 278.995 618.44 278.177C623.598 276.212 627.991 279.306 631.565 283.351C637.212 289.744 639.053 297.426 640.262 305.614C641.56 314.398 643.161 323.227 645.624 331.744C652.409 355.225 653.423 378.901 646.273 402.169C639.391 424.574 639.711 447.547 638.155 470.415C637.986 472.86 639.684 475.429 640.511 477.936C642.805 476.585 645.064 475.162 647.402 473.891C652.302 471.224 655.308 467.436 657.211 461.968C657.975 459.772 662.839 459.008 665.836 457.594V461.257C664.609 472.726 663.302 484.187 662.172 495.665C660.856 509.063 659.078 522.195 652.871 534.553C650.381 539.514 647.18 538.029 643.863 538.029C640.582 538.029 638.661 536.411 638.635 532.731C638.599 527.885 635.86 524.133 631.396 523.297C624.478 522.017 617.338 521.421 610.304 521.51C606.018 521.564 597.677 534.491 597.152 540.803C596.032 540.67 594.885 540.697 593.836 540.386C585.53 537.878 577.163 538.332 570.565 543.782C558.027 554.14 546.787 550.139 535.467 542.253C534.338 541.47 533.102 539.648 533.279 538.527C533.466 537.345 535.129 536.091 536.436 535.46C536.436 535.46 539.575 531.788 540.367 528.507" fill="#EAF0FA"/>
<path id="areaB-name" fill...
```

I tried implementing the following by referring to the codes that assign ids to child elements and change styles in css, but it didn't work.

```
const StyledIconVirtualMap = styled(IconVirtualMap)`
  #areaA-name > path {
    fill: orange;
  }
`;
// or

const StyledIconVirtualMap = styled(IconVirtualMap)`
  path {
   #areaA-name {
     fill: orange;
   }
  }
`;

const VirtualMap = () => (
  <Layout>
    <StyledIconVirtualMap />
  </Layout>
);
```

How can I use `styled-components` to give an id for each `<path>` tag that composes svg, and change the color when mouse over through that id?

Comment: Can you add your code in Codesandbox?